# How to Prevent React Dropdown Menu from disappearing when I try to hover over it?

Tags: reactjs

So I have this Navbar that shows the dropdown menu whenever I hover over it

```
       <li>
        <Link
          to='/'
          className='nav-links'
          onClick={() => setClick(false)}
          onMouseEnter={() => setDropdown(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setDropdown(false)}
        >
          Home
        </Link>
        {dropdown && <Dropdown />}
      </li>
```

My issue is when I try to hover over the actual dropdown menu it disappears since the onMouseEnter is only set on the `<Link>` tag

Here is the Dropdown Component Code

```
      function Dropdown() {
        return (
          <>
            <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
              {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={index}>
                    <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                      {item.title}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </>
        );
      }

      export default Dropdown;
```

CSS that displays the Dropdown

```
      .dropdown-menu {
        background: red;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        list-style: none;
      }

      .dropdown-menu li {
        background: yellow;
        padding: 16px;
      }
```

How would I prevent the dropdown from disappearing whenever I hover over the `<Link>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass to the Dropdown component in props a function that calls `setDropdown(true)` and one that calls `setDropdown(false)`. Then in the Dropdown component get the functions from props and call them on mouseEnter and mouseLeave.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work you should assign onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave to the "li" tag.
Otherwise it won't be working because you leave the area of the Link with your mouse.

Comment: the issue is my li isn't covering 100% of its container height, so that space tiny gap between the navbar and the dropdown has nothing in that space, so it ends up closing the dropdown

Comment: Then I don't think it is possible to do. If there is a space between Link and Dropdown how would you distinguish leaving Link without going to Dropdown between leaving Link and going to Dropdown? There is no such a magic. I think you should recreate your code in a way that Link is exactly next to Dropdown

Comment: so I updated it and got it to work, but the issue now is that I'm repeating the same code over and over by copying onMouseenter & onMouseLeave in each li tag. Do you know how I can prevent adding repetitive code in the li tags?

Comment: It is probably too late, but you could create a custom `li` component in React with predefined onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave logic.